# How can I apply SSL to every page?

Tags: linux, .htaccess, ssl, centos, certificate

just got my SSL Certificate. I set it up.
So now, I want to setup SSL on every page. Is there any way to force SSL on every page?
I have tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks

Comment: If you really want to force SSL properly, it's the HSTS headers you need, and preferably correct links. (See [this on Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/28443/11628)).

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```